# Sending a HTTP Request Post in Json

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-2010, qt

I 'm having what is follow:

```
void MainWindow::uploadText(){
QUrl parameters;
parameters.addQueryItem("OrgName","MM");
parameters.addQueryItem("Type","Article");
parameters.addQueryItem("ExpiraryDate","12/2/2012");

QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://xxxxxxxxxx"));
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

QNetworkAccessManager *manager= new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this, SLOT(sendReportToServerReply(QNetworkReply*)));
QNetworkReply *reply = manager->post(request,parameters.encodedQuery());
```

}

At which level I have to deal with the Json parse and serialization format in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Qt5 then there's JSON serialisation libraries already built in, if you're not you'll need an external one such as: [qt-json](https://github.com/ereilin/qt-json). You do the serialisation and then add it into the header, however you may need to manually build the header instead of using `addQueryItem`.

Comment: addQueryItem thus would give nothing?

Comment: https://github.com/ereilin/qt-json/blob/master/json.cpp All of that should be included in my project????

Comment: Yes, if you add the necessary `.cpp` and `.h` it'll compile in like anything else.

Comment: What is meant by Serialisation?